# Diagonalization of a perturbed matrix with degeneracy

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I'm looking for a way tho change the output of the Eigensystem function in case of degeneracy. Consider the following example:

```
m = {{6, t, 0, t}, {0, 2, t, t}, {t, t, 4, t}, {0, t, t, 4}};

Round[Eigensystem[m /. t -> 0.001], 0.001]
```

with output

```
{{6., 4.001, 3.999,  2.}, {{1., 0., 0.001, 0.}, {0., -0.001, -0.707, -0.707}, {0., 0., -0.707, 0.707}, {0., -1., 0., 0.}}}
```

The eigenvectors 2 and 3 are written as `{0., -0.001, -0.707, -0.707}, {0., 0., -0.707, 0.707}`, but, since t is small, I want them to be written in a shape closer to `{0., -0.001, 0., 1.}, {0., 0., 1., 0.}`.

Is there a way to do so?
Thanks

Comment: You can certainly just find and replace the block matrix of those entries, but then you must ask yourself if the result is still meaningful, that is, if it makes physical or mathematical sense.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by: "I want them to be written in a shape closer to...". Strictly, as long as t is not zero, the eigenvectors are not degenerate and you can not mix them.
However,if you are willing to make small errors, you may neglect -0.001 in:{0., -0.001, -0.707, -0.707} and then you may rotate the vectors:

```
s2 = -Sqrt[2];
tm = RotationMatrix[{{s2, s2}, {0, 1}}]/2;
Print["Rotated first vector:", tm.{c, c}]
Print["Rotated second vector:", tm.{c, -c}]
```

The full rotated vectors are not quit eigenvectors with an eigenvalue of 4 and an error of approx. 0.001:

```
m = {{6, t, 0, t}, {0, 2, t, t}, {t, t, 4, t}, {0, t, t, 4}}/.t->0.001;
v1 = {0., -0.001, 0, 1};
v2 = {0., 0, 1, 0};
Print["m.v1=",m.v1];
Print["m.v2=",m.v2];
```

Comment: Is there a way to make Mathematica give immediately an output close to what you get after rotating?

Comment: Simply set t to zero.

Comment: Setting t equal to zero is not what I need. I want to see some deviation out of the vector `{0,0,1,0}`.

Answer (score 1):

"You can't always get what you want.." Rolling Stones.
For t==0 you have freedom to choose the degenerate eigenvectors in a 2 dim space to your liking.
Hover, if you perturb your matrix (t != 0), the eigenvectors are fixed, there is no more freedom to choose. That means, if you start at t == 0 with: {0,0,1,0} and {0,0,0,1}, the eigenvectors jump non continuously to different vectors as soon as t !=0.
You can watch this by:

```
Manipulate[
 ev = Eigenvectors[{{6, t, 0, t}, {0, 2, t, t}, {t, t, 4, t}, {0, t, 
      t, 4}}][[2 ;; 3]];
  NumberForm[Grid[ev], {1, 3}] 
 , {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: I think that we code and produce results to solve problems and face new challenges. This is the spirit of me while producing results, especially because this is my job and I get paid for that. To me, stack exchange is a way to fasten my research and make it easier. If you can't help me I am completely fine. This simply means I will find a solution myself. You can't do that is not an excuse not to get there. Thank you anyways.